# Fake a static method of a non-static class

Tags: c#, microsoft-fakes, shim

I have a non-static class with a static method that I want to shim it.

```
public class MyClass
{
    static MyClass()
    {
        //do constructor things
    }
    public static void MyMethod(string str)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This static method is called from some part of the code I want to test (*MyClass.MyMethod("some string")*), but I'm not interested on MyMethod behavior. I need to shim it.
My try is:

```
MyClassNamespace.Fakes.ShimMyClass.MyMethod = ("some string") => {};
```

But MyMethod is missing, I believe because the class is not static.

How can I shim it like it was a static class?
I have read that it's possible to shim the Contructor and simulate some methods, and maybe that is a better choice, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You mean a public static field or property like: `public static Action<string> MyMethod = s => {};`

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Could you explain it to me more clearly? What you mean is that I need to implement a property that calles the method?

Comment: U, You need something like a public variable where you can store a custom method/action. I'm not sure if you meant something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the Shim on `AllInstances`

```
MyClassNamespace.Fakes.ShimMyClass.AllInstances.MyMethodString = ("some string") => {};
```

If you notice in above code the name of method in generated shim is with parameter type (that's the way Shims are generated).

Comment: I see, but I cannot find the method after AllInstances, with or without parameter type... In fact I cannot see any method, just _Equals_ and _ReferenceEquals_

Comment: Is the fakes are being generated for your class/assembly properly? Can you please see Shim/Stub are generated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure for 100% what you mean, but it looks like you want to store an static action.

In my example you assign a lambda expression to the static field. The instances can call this Action:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static Action<string> LogMehod;

    public void Log(string s)
    {
        // call the static log method if it is assigned.
        if(LogMehod != null)
            LogMehod(User + ": " + s);
    }
    public string User {get;set;}
}

class Program
{
    static Main()
    {
        // assign an lambda expression, which displays the passed string.
        MyClass.LogMehod = s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }

        // create an instance of MyClass
        var user1 = new MyClass();
        user1.User = "User1";
        user1.Log("bla");

        var user2 = new MyClass();
        user2.User = "User2";
        user2.Log("also bla");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Gives:

```
User1: bla
User2: also bla
```